# Hibernate intermediate/advanced tutorials

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

Let's say I have a reasonably good understanding of Hibernate, but want to have a more in-depth knowledge of it, namely:

- how hibernate caches work
- Objects lifecycle
- Use with applicaton containers, etc.

Can you recommend a short(ish) tutorial that would provide this information ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the standard [references](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html) very exhaustive and maintained.

**Update**: getting started for version 5.0: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/quickstart/html/

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend learning about [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) so you start moving from hibernate to a standard approach.